# How to use AFNetworking in static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I'm using CocoaPods to manage dependency. Let say the old project named A, and I have the workspace A and project Pods (including AFNetworking, GoogleAnalytics, SBJson....)

I now want to separate my core network function into a static library. I have created the new static library named B and add it into workspace A. However, the library cannot use the AFNetworking, or SBJson anymore.

I do search over the internet but no luck.

I have tried to do the following code in Podfile but no luck as well

```
workspace 'A.xcworkspace'

platform :ios, :deployment_target => '7.0'

xcodeproj 'A.xcodeproj'

pod 'SBJson', '~> 3.2'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1.0'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.0.3'
pod 'AMSlideOutController'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'

target :B, :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'B.xcodeproj'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'SBJson', '~> 3.2'
end
```

Could you please help me how to solve this issue? I need something like the both main project and static library can also use AFNetworking or SBJson.

Cheers,

Comment: You are trying to access AFNetworking from static library. AFNetworking is in Pods?.

Comment: Yes. AFNetworking in Pods and I want my static library can access it.